# how to store object type field in mysql using sails

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I want that my model fields will store in mysql as it is. My user model is like this:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    local: {
      email: 'string',
      password: 'string'
    },
    facebook: {
      id: 'string',
      token: 'string',
      email: 'string',
      name: 'string'
    },
    google: {
      id: 'string',
      token: 'string',
      email: 'string',
      name: 'string'
    }
  }
};
```

But this does not create any field in user model. What should I do for storing these fields in mysql ?

Comment: Can we see your `config/connections.js` and `config/models.js` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to save them as JSON objects. Sails will stringify your objects and save the result in your database. It will also take care of the parsing, so you don't have to worry about that. Still it doesn't allow specifying the inner attributes of the objects, but I don't think there's a solution for that.

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    local: {
      type: 'json'
    },
    facebook: {
      type: 'json'
    },
    google: {
      type: 'json'
    }
  }
};
```